# Why is k=1 in linear discriminant analysis for two classes?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, dimensionality-reduction

With two classes, why does Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) consider only
projecting onto one dimension (k=1)? Normally, even with 2 classes, you can consider
projecting the d-dimensional original feature vector onto any k-dimensional space.